# How to write independent/isolated express middleware with access to raw request body

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to write an [Express](http://expressjs.com/) middleware that has access to the raw request body. So something like this *(actually works and)* would be ideal:

```
const middleware = [
  express.raw({ type: '*/*' }),
  (req, res, next) => {
    digest(req.body);
    next();
  },
];
```

However, this approach means the `req.body` has now been streamed/processed and is now unavailable to any handler or middleware following my middleware:

```
app.post(route, middleware, (req, res) => res.send(req.body)); // returns `{}`
```

I would it to be possible to use my middleware with other body parsers. So this should be ok:

```
app.use(express.json());
app.post(route, middleware, (req, res) => res.send(req.body)); // should return the JSON body posted not `{}`
```

As well as this:

```
app.post(route, middleware, express.json(), (req, res) => res.send(req.body)); // should return the JSON body posted not `{}`
```

Is it possible to:

- use middlewares in the manner I am attempting here *(i.e. using more than one in succession)*?
- get hold of the raw body by a means other than `express.raw({ type: '*/*' })`?
- reset the request body after I am done with it so other handlers and middlewares can access it like my middleware had never been used?

I have expanded these snippets into a failing [test](https://bitbucket.org/j1n3l0/demo-propagate-request-body) in this repository if the above is not clear enough and would appreciate any help or pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with a bit more research *(and sleep)* I think my approach here is probably incorrect.

A more appropriate solution would be to use the `verify` option of the relevant body parser which gives you access to the buffer:

```js
app.use(express.json({ verify: (req, res, buf, encoding) => digest(buf) || throw 'Invalid Digest' }));
app.post(route, (req, res) => res.send(req.body));
```